# Can you use mobile boarding passes at Antalya Airport?

Tags: airports, turkey, ayt

When I was at Antalya Airport I noticed that I'd have to be handed a physical boarding pass when checking in as I couldn't check in online.

I scanned my boarding pass with an app and it created an equivalent barcode in the phone. However, the guy at security refused to even scan my phone and asked for my paper one.

Later at the gate one half of my boarding pass was torn off and I was handed just a small piece of it.

Can you not use mobile boarding passes at Antalya Airport?

Comment: To me, the title doesn’t match the question. A copy of a barcode from a paper boarding pass isn’t a mobile boarding pass. I would be very hesitant to rely on such a home made boarding pass at any airport, and acceptance of a proper mobile boarding pass is no guarantee a home made one will be.

Comment: Yes, that's my point.

Comment: @MJeffryes the agent at security shouldn't be able to tell any difference between my mobile boarding pass and a real one...

Comment: @MJeffryes typo... It looks just like any other mobile boarding pass...

Comment: If you say so. I'm simply saying that there is a distinction between a homemade boarding pass, and a mobile boarding pass officially offered by the airline. I wouldn't rely on the former.

Comment: @MJeffryes I did keep the paper one - not the first time my home-made tickets are failing 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both facilities may differ from one airline to another. For example [Turkish Airlines](https://www.turkishairlines.com/en-gb/any-questions/check-in/airport-check-in-options/index.html) have self-service kiosks at Antalya Airport, but do not have mobile pass facility.

[image: Antalya Airport]

[Pegasus Airlines](https://www.flypgs.com/en/useful-info/info-about-flights/check-in#accordion-1) indicate that they have self-service kiosks only for passengers travelling without luggage.

> Currently, Pegasus Self-Service kiosks are for passengers flying
>   without luggage from Adana, Ankara, **Antalya**, Bodrum, Dalaman, Istanbul
>   - Ataturk, Istanbul Sabiha Gökcen, Izmir, Konya and Lefkosa - Ercan Airports.

Comment: What's an online boarding pass?

Comment: An online boarding pass is when you check in online (select your seat online) and get a/an "(online) boarding pass". When you go to the airport you show this boarding pass, and _only_ check in your luggage.

Comment: @3kstc pas you have that online boarding pass in your phone or do you have to print it?

Comment: @MikaelDúiBolinder it doesn't matter hard/soft copy - but I always have a hard copy for "just in case" moments (ie flat battery, or if I lose my phone, etc.) as long as you can show that _you have_ the online boarding pass you will be fine.